# How to enable dropdown on searchbox in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am designing searchBox wich has a select(dropdown )  at the right side but when i press on dropdown nothing happens means that i don't see dropdown list items  ,i don't know why is not listening to onclick. please help me.

i want to do sothing like this but combo box does not work :
[image: Search box with dropdown]

My code:

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-      toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span    class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
 </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-   toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span     class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello  You are not identifying the class at the first place  by writing

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ></button>
```

refer the the class name first it will work something like this

```
 <button class="btn btn-default type="button"></button>
```

use this dropdown code

```
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- 
  toggle="dropdown">Action
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

and for the Whole Work  details Check the below Fiddle I updated Your Work

[DropDown Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/DTcHh/26808/)

Comment: Thank @Assifuzzaman  Redoy . for the link of yours above it works but form me it doesn't i begin to guess if is javascript links or js link which has a problem .

Comment: `you must add the link but i did it with exactly your code what you have provided.please read the above description if you added the cdns it will work

Answer (score 0):

I can't clearly under stand your problem but as i understood 
if you want to make drop down list you should use

```
<select class="dropdown-menu">
  <option><a href="#">Action</a></option> 
  <option><a href="#">Another action</a></option> 
  <option><a href="#">Something else here</a></option>
  <option role="separator" class="divider"></option> 
  <option><a href="#">Separated link</a></option>  
</select>
```

The Result will be This :
[image: When using Select options]

like this http://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected

and if you want to Selects a subset of items from array use **Filters**
like this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

I hope to be useful

Comment: for sure you must use this

Comment: for sure you must use this  <select class="dropdown-menu">
      <option><a href="#">Action</a></option>
      <option><a href="#">Another action</a></option>
      <option><a href="#">Something else here</a></option>
      <option role="separator" class="divider"></option>
      <option><a href="#">Separated link</a></option>
    </select>

Comment: @Kabera Mugwaneza Alexis  i updated my answer take alook on it

Comment: Nice idea ?@Amal . but don't work for me help me to check if is not boot strap contents  i linked wrong